# CSS - greater than selector - select items greater than N 

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have several `<p>` elements in my HTML body. I only want to show the first two paragraphs, and set `display:none` to all paragraphs after. Why does the following code not work?

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        p:gt(2) { display:none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
</body> 

</html>
```

My code still shows all 4 paragraph elements in Chrome web browser.

How do I correct my code to achieve the objective I originally stated?

Comment: :gt(2) is a jQuery specific thing as far as I know.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If they're siblings the easiest approach with some backwards compatibility would be:

```
p + p ~ p {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NBurh/).

You could also use:

```
p:nth-of-type(2) ~ p {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/NBurh/1/).

References:

- [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).
- [CSS `:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo).
- [Adjacent sibling (`+`) combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).
- [General sibling (`~`) combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

Comment: @BoltClock: absolutely, but at the time of writing that suggestion was already posted elsewhere and, while its inclusion would have improved this answer, it'd feel too much like shameless copying (even if I attributed it to the original author).

Answer (score 6):

:gt is just a jQuery short hand, 
to select it in css:

```
p:nth-of-type(n+3)
```

Comment: It's not "just a jQuery shorthand". It's a completely different selector.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sibling selector:

```
p + p + p {display:none;}
```

Other than the first two, it selects all!

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KK3mk/