# Show/Hide specified number of table rows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a HTML page with multiple number of tables, each containing large number of rows. These table rows are taking too much space on the webpage so i am trying to create a Show/Hide link below each table that will only display a specified number of rows. I found out some scripts on STACKOVERFLOW but couldn't get them work for some reason. Any help would be appreciated ...

This is an example of the tables:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="98%" class="dir_cat">
<tr><th><a href="/posts/10-Auto/">Auto</a></th></tr>
<tr class="Auto"><td><a href="/Cars/">Cars</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Auto"><td><a href="/Accessories/">Car Accessories</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Auto"><td><a href="/Detailing/">Car Detailing</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Auto"><td><a href="/Car-Audio/">Car Audio</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Auto"><td><a href="/Motorcycles/">Motorcycles</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Auto"><td><a href="/Commercial-Vehicles/">Other Commercial Vehicles</a></td></tr>
</table>
<a href="#">Show/Hide Categories</a>
<br>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="98%" class="dir_cat">
<tr><th><a href="0/posts/10-Auto/">Antiques</a></th></tr>
<tr class="Antiques"><td><a href="/Arch/">Architectural</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Antiques"><td><a href="/Art-Deco/">Art Deco</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Antiques"><td><a href="/Art-Nouveau/">Art Nouveau</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Antiques"><td><a href="/Asian-Antiques/">Asian Antiques</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Antiques"><td><a href="/Books/">Books</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Antiques"><td><a href="/Publications/">Publications</a></td></tr>
</table>    
<a href="#">Show/Hide Categories</a>    
<br>

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="98%" class="dir_cat">
<tr><th><a href="/Art/">Art</a></th></tr>
<tr class="Art"><td><a href="Aboriginal/">Aboriginal</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Art"><td><a href="/Art-Cards/">Art Cards</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Art"><td><a href="/Drawings/">Drawings</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Art"><td><a href="/Fabric-Art/">Fabric Art</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Art"><td><a href="/Folk-Art/">Folk Art</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Art"><td><a href="/Mixed-Media/">Mixed-Media</a></td></tr>
<tr class="Art"><td><a href="/Publications/">Publications</a></td></tr>
</table>    
<a href="#">Show/Hide Categories</a>    
<br>
```

JS:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("table tr:gt(3)").toggle();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17dnu0e4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will better guarantee that all the appropriate TR elements toggle in sympathy. Otherwise, depending on their inital state, some could toggle OFF while others toggle ON - ie antiphase!

HTML

```
...
<a class="tableToggler" href="#">Show/Hide Categories</a>
```

jQuery

```
$("a.tableToggler").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tr = $(this).prev("table").find("tr:eq(4)").toggle();//toggle tr:eq(4).
    $tr.nextAll().toggle(!$tr.is(":hidden"));//set all following trs to be the same as tr:eq(4).
}).prev("table").find("tr:eq(4)").show().end().end().trigger('click');//this will guarantee that each tr:eq(4) is ON, then toggle it and its fellow TRs to OFF.
```

This may seem OTT, but the penalty for safety is very minor. I had to do something similar once to fix an earlier screw-up.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, you need to make your selector only match rows in the table brefore the link, not all tables.

Second, you need to use `event.preventDefault()` to keep from following the links when you click on them.

Third, you should give these links a distinct class, so that you don't bind your handler to all links on the page.

```
$("a.showhide").click(function (event) {
    $(this).prev("table").find("tr:gt(3)").toggle();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/17dnu0e4/6/)

Comment: Thanks, I am still looking for a solution to hide the categories by default.

Comment: You can do that in CSS. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554098/css-greater-than-selector-select-items-greater-than-n

Answer (score 0):

you are finding all `table` and toggling.

find the previous sibling of the clicked link and toggle:

```
$(this).prev().find("tr:gt(3)")
```

See the updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/17dnu0e4/5/

Comment: Thanks, Your solution worked for me. Is it possible to hide the categories by default? They should be visible only after "Show/Hide" Link is clicked.